# c error :expected expression before 'int'

Tags: c

this is my demo .

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sqsum(int a, ...)
{
    va_list list;
    int b = 0,n = a;
    va_start(list,a);
    while(n > 0)
        {
            b = b+n*n;
            n = va_arg(list,int);
        }
    va_end(list);
    return b;
}

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    printf("%d\n",sqsum(1,2,3,-1));
    return 0;
}
```

then I compile this demo , it occurs this error ,I donot know this error mean.

Comment: Well to start off, what is the error saying?

Comment: @Ryan It's the error in the title, I think. Niklaus, what line is the error on?

Comment: Do you have `#include <stdarg.h>`?

Comment: Errors in C also have a line number. Help us to help you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you did not include `#include <stdarg.h>` and it does not look like you did, then that would explain the error you are seeing, otherwise the program looks correct. If I do not include that header these are the errors I see using `gcc`:

```
In function ‘sqsum’:
13:29: error: expected expression before ‘int’
```

Comment: I was able to compile it fine after adding #include <stdarg.h>

Comment: @Niklaus The error message indicates that line 13 is where your error was. Which google search keyword would you combine with "opengroup" to find a manual for `va_arg` (line 13)?

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour Oh,I forgot include stdarg.h head file.